# Flink taskmanager metrics disappear after starting a job

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Standalone cluster (with jobmanager and taskmanager on same machine) on 1.14.4 and I'm testing the migration to 1.15.0

But I keep losing the taskmanager metrics when I start a job on the 1.15 cluster

I use the same configuration as in the previous cluster

```
  metrics.reporters: prom
  metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
  metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9251
```

If the cluster is running without jobs I can see the metrics on port 9250 for jobmanager and on port 9251 for taskmanager

If I start a job, the metrics from taskmanager disappear and if I stop the job the metrics come live again

What am I missing?

### Response

Its a bug on metrics of kafka source and sink on 1.15.0
https://lists.apache.org/thread/6bd9vmcroh7576d7h1kdcd8czf0b4l73

Is necessary to disable the registration of metrics on both

For source:

```
kafkaSourceBuilder.setProperty("register.consumer.metrics", "false");
```

For sink:

```
var producerProperties = new Properties();
producerProperties.setProperty("register.producer.metrics", "false");
producerSinkBuilder.setKafkaProducerConfig(producerProperties);
```

Comment: Maybe try with `metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9260,9261` ?

Comment: Its a bug on metrics of KafkaSource and KafkaSink. 
Edited the question with answer..